# Unable to login my subdirectory WordPress site

Tags: login, directory

I am trying to build a new website in my existing website's subdirectory folder. I have installed WordPress to [www.fitfix.ca/new](http://www.fitfix.ca/new) subdirectory. I can access to the page but when try to login fitfix.ca/new/wp-admin This page isn’t working right now fitfix.ca redirected you too many times appears. I tried to change plugin/theme name and deleting htaccess file but nothing worked. What's the solution please help.

Answer (score 0):

Look in the site's error.log file for hints. A 'white screen' will cause entries in the error.log file (in the site's root folder - the 'new' folder).

You might also try to rename the plugin's folder in case it is a plugin.

You also need a basic htaccess file - see here for info: https://wordpress.org/support/article/htaccess/ . If the htaccess file is not proper, then the site won't load.